# Excel Date Dependent Drop down list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I'm creating an excel sheet that has a variety of columns, but the one in question is the dates column.
Could it be done that the operator of the sheet types in todays date into say A2 (the date column), and then all subsequent rows of A are a drop down of either todays date or the next two subsequent days?

Comment: Sure, e.g. per VBA scripting.

Comment: @dude what does that mean? lol

Comment: That means that you can try to write a VBA-Macro to achieve your goal and ask for a help if you stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to even fill **A1**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=TODAY()+ROWS($1:1)-1
```

and copy downwards.  Then set the **DV** for a column **A** cell to `List`:

[image]

Then copy this cell down the column.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by following these steps:

1. Add another sheet to your workbook to hold the drop down list
   content.
2. Create a link on this new sheet to cell A2 in the original sheet.
3. Use formulas to populate the next two fields on the new sheet with subsequent dates.
4. Use Data Validation -> Allow List.

`Source:` should point to the cells on your new Sheet.

Comment: what kind of formulas populate cells with subsequent dates?

Comment: On worksheet 2, if cell A1 contains the link to the date cell on worksheet 1, then in cell A2 put the equation "=A1+1".  Excel interprets that as adding 1 day to the referenced date.